# Sparc Function compilation alignment

Tags: c, embedded, ada, memory-alignment, sparc

I want my program such that each function in the binary has some space left after it ends. So that later if some minor change is required only that function is changed with the extra space acting as room for accounting the minor change. -falign-function can do the job but it will not give consistent space. Is there anyway to do it? Or better way to do it?

Comment: Why do you care about the sizes used by functions inside the compiled binary?

Comment: Imagine a satellite running a binary. We discover an error in a function. Rather than uplinking full binary(which is costly in terms of bandwidth). Just uplink the new function.

Comment: Hmm, well, in this case why not compile every function into it's own library and "link" at run-time?

Comment: That is not possible for a team. And moreover is it going to give holes between functions ?

Comment: "*That is not possible for a team.*" not possible interms of what?

Comment: Well, but how do I insert NOP between function during compilation? Is there a flag for it? I didnt get what solution you proposed actually

Comment: Oh well Run time linking is not possible. We run a single binary without MMU. We dont have a operating system actually

Answer (score 2):

You could use an inline assembly statement to add a series of nops at the start (or end) of each function. Then later when you need to modify the function, you could remove some of the nops to keep the overall size of the function the same. For example:

```
int foo(...) {
   __asm__ __volatile__("nop; nop; nop; nop;" ::);
   ...
}
```

Or you could even reserve large chunks of memory in the function with something like this:

```
__asm__ __volatile__("ba,a 1f; .skip 1000; 1: ;" ::);
```

This reserves a big chunk of memory and simply branches around it in the code.

Comment: There is just one problem. Our language is actually Ada and not C. We dont have macros in ada as far as I know !

Comment: It would be helpful to know about such constraints in advance. ;) But I wouldn't be so quick to give up on inline assembly. If you are using a gcc/ada compiler, you ought to have inline assembly. If not, you may be able to just add extra ada code that has no effect, and use that to pad the original function. Then remove the padding a little at a time as you need to add new (real) code.

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I understand you are trying to append real code after each function. But Isnt it better and elegant to do that in linker script level ? -ffunction-align=32 gives me some space I would rather go with that. I tried by using -ffunction-sections and putting QUAD(0) at the end of .text section, but no luck. Maybe I am missing something?

Comment: Sure, if you can figure out a way to solve this with a linker script, then that is certainly better. The trouble with function align is that you can't predict how much extra space you'll get. You may not get any. Using code padding it will at least be predictable. And since you are talking about options like -ffunction-sections, you are evidently using gcc, so that means you ought to be able to use inline assembly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a sufficiently new compiler, they have recently added a new option: `-fprolog-pad=N` and `-fprolog-pad=M,N` which means issue M nops before the function an N nops after it.

Comment: I have not tested it. But that is nice ! Thanks l.

Comment: It looks as though this is proposed but not yet included; as of 1 March they were still arguing about the option’s name!