# Pad each function with fixed number of nops

Tags: linker, ada, linker-scripts

I want to pad each function with a required number of nops using linker script. I figured I would need -ffunction-sections switch during compilation. And  add some QUAD(0) in the .text() defination of linker script. But it seems it is not working. Basically I need to pad each function with fixed number of bytes ( not for alignment purposes ). How do I go about it ?

Comment: For Context, Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: Imagine a satellite running a binary. We discover an error in a function. Rather than uplinking full binary(which is costly in terms of bandwidth). Just uplink the new function.

Comment: I don’t think this question has anything specifically to do with [tag:ada]!

Comment: Well, I thought someone will tell me to add macro of nops at end of each function in C. So to avoid that I put a tag that language is ada. Macros are not possible.

Comment: Some Ada implementations allow inline assembly on certain targets, for [example](https://docs.adacore.com/gnat_ugn-docs/html/gnat_ugn/gnat_ugn/inline_assembler.html).

Comment: What system is this?

Comment: Whatever approach you take, how will you ensure that the compiler will not optimize the nop statements out of the executable?

Comment: @JimRogers, that’s the reason Prakhar wants to work linker script magic - i.e. post-compilation.

Comment: System is a Sparc V8 based processor.   If there would have been switch to add prologue and epilogue of nops !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sparc Function compilation alignment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166369/sparc-function-compilation-alignment)